# How to get field edited by comparing before-edited instance to current instance

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to log field changed when making edits to a user, however, I'm struggling to compare the old user instance to the current user instance and retrieve the field(s) that are different.

As of now when running the conditional inside the for loop, it prints all the fields related to the model, and not the field edited.

I'm also struggling to get the value of the fields looped through.

Method:

```
def log_user_change(old_user_instance, request):

        user = User.objects.get(pk = old_user_instance.id)

        user_fields = user._meta.get_fields()
        old_user_fields = old_user_instance._meta.get_fields()

        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(user)

        for old_user_fields in user_fields:
            if not old_user_fields in user_fields:

                field_values = getattr(old_user_instance, old_user_fields.attname)

                print('Changed field:')
                print(old_user_fields)
                print('Values:')
                print(field_values)

                """
                ChangeLog.objects.log_updae(
                    user = request,
                    content_type = ct.pk,
                    object_id = user.pk,
                    changes = user_fields,
                )
                """
```

View:

```
def editUser(request, pk):

    # Query appropriate user based on pk returned in url
    user = User.objects.get(pk = pk)

    # Get the EditUserForm and add the user as instance
    edit_user_form = EditUserForm(instance = user)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Bind data to the form class, and add the user as instance
        edit_user_form = EditUserForm(request.POST, error_class=DivErrorList, instance = user)

        old_user_instance = User.objects.get(pk = pk)

        # Validate form inputs
        if edit_user_form.is_valid():

            # Save edits
            edit_user_form.save()


            # Log change
            ChangeLog.log_user_change(old_user_instance, request.user.id)

        else:
            # error

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'edit_user_form': edit_user_form,
    }

    # Render request, template and context
    return render(request, 'users/backend/user/user_edit.html', context)
```

Comment: `user._meta.get_fields()` will get all the fields defined on the model so testing for common fields in `user_fields` and `old_user_fields` will always return `True` as the same fields will be in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over `User._meta.get_fields()` to loop over all fields defined on the model and then using `gettattr` get the value for the old and new instance and then compare them

```
def log_user_change(old_user_instance):
    new_user_instance = User.objects.get(pk=old_user_instance.pk)
    for field in User._meta.get_fields():
        if isinstance(field, models.ManyToOneRel):
            continue
        old_value = getattr(old_user_instance, field.name)
        new_value = getattr(new_user_instance, field.name)
        if old_value != new_value:
            print('Changed field:', field.name)
            print('Old value:', old_value, 'New value:', new_value)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am, however, running into an error on the line `old_value = getattr(old_user_instance, field.name)`. It returns `'User' object has no attribute 'logentry'`. Is it my models that's improperly configured?

Comment: Ah, yes you should probably filter out the reverse relations that `get_fields()` returns. Updated the answer